# Put Carousel buttons on top of image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have a bootstrap carousel, and buttons, which I want to go on top of the images in order to change from image to image. No matter what I do, I cannot seem to get it to be on top, it always shows up under.

I have tried position relative on the outer most div, and position relative on the carousel-control div. Any suggestions?

```
HTML:

<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide"  data-interval="false" data-ride="carousel">
   <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
     <div class="carousel-item active">
       <img class="mini-img" src="images/plane.png" alt="">
     </div>
     <div class="carousel-item active">
       <img class="mini-img" src="images/truck.png" alt="">
     </div>
     <div class="carousel-item active">
       <img class="mini-img" src="images/boat.png" alt="">
     </div>
     <div class="carousel-controls">
        <ul class="carousel-ul">
           <li>
             <button type="button" name="button"></button>
           </li>
           <li>
             <button type="button" name="button"></button>
           </li>
           <li>
             <button type="button" name="button"></button>
           </li>
           <li>
             <button type="button" name="button"></button>
           </li>
           <li>
             <button type="button" name="button"></button>
           </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>



CSS: 

    #carouselExampleControls {
      position: relative;
    }

    .carousel-controls {
      position: absolute;
    }

    .carousel-ul {
      position: absolute;
      list-style-type: none;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

my suggestion is using jquery because when you want to custom bootstrap the best way is using jquery for example you can make a button outside your div and call a jquery function like this :
consider your buttons id is `#nextButton` and `#prevButton`

`$('#nextButton').onClick(function(){
   $('.carousel').carousel('next');
})`

`$('#prevButton').onClick(function(){
   $('.carousel').carousel('prev');
})`

and for more info you can check this [link](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/carousel/) out

Comment: I can get the slides to move with buttons, but I cannot get the buttons to appear on top of the image - they come out below the carousel entirely.

Comment: could you just run it in fiddlejs or some where else to see your result

Comment: I am using boostrap, so you would not be able to see it. How do you position something, on top of something else?

Comment: with position absoult and put some top and left on it

Answer (score 1):

```
.carousel-ul {
      position: absolute;
      top:0;
    }
```

or in html

```
<ul class="carousel-ul" style="position: absolute; top:0;">
```

it's work for me